# Default value for profiles in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have multiple profiles and there are lots of attributes(which will grow), I don't want to set each attribute every time in a different profile.

I have an *application.yml* file like this:

```
  freemarker:
    template-loader-path: classpath:/templates

  datasource:
    username: postgres
    password: mypass
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver

  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create

  security:
    secret: "jwt_secret_key_it_is_a_random_key_229"
    loginTokenExpiration: 86400
    confirmUserTokenExpiration: 86400
    devTokenExpiration: 157680000
    tokenPrefix: "Bearer"
    headerString: "Authorization"
    signUpUrl: "/token/login"

mysite:
  apiTosUrl: "https://example.com/api-tos"
  fromEmail: "alert@example.com"
  firstFreeCredits: 10

junction:
  port: 9080
  hasBasicAuth: false

---

spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev

---

spring:
  profiles: stage

  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update

chargeBee:
  site: "example.chargebee.com"
  apiKey: "mykey"

---

spring:
  profiles: prod

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/myproddb

  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update

chargeBee:
  site: "example.chargebee.com"
  apiKey: "myapikey"
```

Most of the settings are common between profiles, and which are not common, I have re-defined it in the corresponding section of the profile.
I am assuming that the first section in this YAML document fills the properties with default values and the corresponding sections overwrite it.

Is this approach correct? If not then how to have an inheritance of properties values such that I define the common value once and for the rest of the profiles, I only need to define the different values?

Answer (score 4):

you can also achieve profile using create the different profile-specific yml file.

you can also be defined by using the following naming convention:

```
application-{profile}.yml
```

Create `application.yml` file. This file loaded first. Load all attribute of `application.yml` file.

Check any active profile found(yes `stage`) then load after successfully load default profile then load `application-stage.yml` file and override existing attribute and add the new attribute.

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: stage
    datasource:
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springbootdb
```

create `application-stage.yml` file same location of `application.yml`.

```
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update

chargeBee:
  site: "example.chargebee.com"
  apiKey: "mykey"
```

create `application-prod.yml` file same location of `application.yml`.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/myproddb

  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update

chargeBee:
  site: "example.chargebee.com"
  apiKey: "myapikey"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes that correct approach to define multiple profiles

> You can specify multiple profile-specific YAML documents in a single
>   file by using a spring.profiles key to indicate when the document
>   applies, as shown in the following example:

See official document [24.6.3 Multi-profile YAML Documents](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

In the below example, if the development profile is active, the `server.address` property is `127.0.0.1.` Similarly, if the production profile is active, the server.address property is `192.168.1.120`. If the `development` and `production` profiles are not enabled, then the value for the property is `192.168.1.100`.

```
server:
    address: 192.168.1.100
---
spring:
    profiles: development
server:
    address: 127.0.0.1
---
spring:
    profiles: production
server:
    address: 192.168.1.120
```

Comment: The doc states that if no profile is active then the 192.168.1.100 value is taken. But what happens if there was an another attribute in the first section called "port" and none of the profile based section defined it. If the production profile was active then would this default value of "port" from the first section would be taken?

Comment: if your profile is active and you override in your profile then it will overridden otherwise default will be loaded so if port is defined and no profile is override port value then default will be loaded..